# How can I revert the order of a list that I generate based on numbers that I get from Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a list of numbers in Firebase that goes from 1 to X number, since it increases every so often... The list is generated without problems, but it is generated downwards, that is, in this way:

```
1
2
3
4
5
...
```

What I need is that it be generated in this way:

```
...
5
4
3
2
1
```

I have tried adding reverse everywhere but it has not worked ...

This is the code I am using:

```
var content = '';  
          firebase.database().ref().child("Users").on('value', function(snapshot){
          if(snapshot.exists()){
            //console.log(snapshot.key)
            content ='<ul>';  
            snapshot.forEach(function(data){
                var val = data.val();

                content += '<li>' + val.Usuario + '</li>';

            });
            content +='</ul>';

            $("#A_Usuarios")append(content);
            }
            });
```

This is the structure of the db

[image]

I hope you can help me, thank you very much!

Comment: You cannot `.reverse()` an object. what is the data structure - not just the values?

Comment: As a sidenote, using non-English variable names is almost always a really bad idea.

Comment: There add the structure of the database

Answer (score 1):

Try add `.sort((a, b) => b.Usuario-a.Usuario)` like this:

```
var content = '';
firebase.database().ref().child("Users").on('value', function (snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
        //console.log(snapshot.key)
        content = '<ul>';
        snapshot
            .sort((a, b) => b.Usuario-a.Usuario)
            .forEach(function (data) {
                var val = data.val();

                content += '<li>' + val.Usuario + '</li>';

            });
        content += '</ul>';

        $("#A_Usuarios").append(content);
    }
});
```

Comment: It generates this error "snapshot.sort is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

It is usually better to have the database sorting your records, instead of having this task done in the front-end.

One common approach for your case is to store the inverse value of the `Usario` field value in, for example, an extra `UsarioInv` field, and use the [`orderByChild()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference.html#order-bychild) method, as follows:

```
var content = '';
firebase.database().ref().child("Users").orderByChild("UsarioInv").on('value', function(snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
        //console.log(snapshot.key)
        content = '<ul>';
        snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
            var val = data.val();

            content += '<li>' + val.Usuario + '</li>';

        });
        content += '</ul>';

        $("#A_Usuarios") append(content);
    }
});
```

Comment: It is a good idea, but the objective is not to generate more values, only to revert the order of those that already exist or to reverse the order of the list <li>

Comment: Duplicating data (or saving extra data which is slightly different like the inverse value) is very common in NoSQL databases. Usually, one uses the update() method to keep the different nodes in synch, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#updating_or_deleting_data